# Vega, square root of time, and ATM straddles

Tags: options, volatility, fx, vega

Could someone intuitively explain why for say a 1y EURUSD option -
If you buy 100 (50/leg of straddle) of 1y at the money EUR vol, that = sq root of 12 x 100 = roughly 350k of EUR vol.
If you buy 100 of 6m EUR vol, that = sq root of 6 x 100 = roughly 245k of EUR vol.
If you buy 100 of 1m EUR vol, that = sq root of 1 x 100 = 100k of EUR vol.
Why does that work?

Or starting from scratch, whats the right formula for calculating vega from the atm straddles?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Black Scholes vega is given as $$ S \cdot \phi(d1)\cdot\sqrt{\tau}  $$

With $\phi$ as $\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and d1 as $\frac{ln(\frac{S}{K}) + (r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2})\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}$.

For ATM straddles, d1 is approximately 0 (or, at least for small $\sigma\sqrt{\tau}$, close to 0), which means that $\phi(d1)$ becomes ~$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, and this approximation is locally insensitive to changes in time to maturity. This simplifies the vega formula to $$ S \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\sqrt{\tau} $$

Which varies with the square root of time, explaining the rule of thumb that you've shown above in the EUR example.

It's worth noting though that even though cash vega exposure increases, the volatility of IV decreases as time to maturity (~sqrt(t))  increases, so the increased dollar risk is offset by decreased underlying risk.

Edit:
For the straddle you multiply vega * 2, so it becomes $$ S \cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\cdot\sqrt{\tau} $$

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have lost me a bit though .. can you plug some numbers in to the final straddle formula to make it clear?

Comment: Okay. With EURUSD at 1.05 for simplicity, your vega in that scenario is 1.05 * sqrt(2/pi) * sqrt(30/365) / 100 ~= 1.05 * 0.8 * 0.3 / 100 = 0.00252 USD change in option value per percent change in IV, this assumes 1 EUR notional per contract, I am not familiar with the specifics but I think 100K is the standard notional size per contract, so per option, your cash vega per 1% change in IV is USD 252. 

Say 15 days has passed and underlying is unchanged your new cash vega is USD 170, which is approx 1/sqrt(2) * your original cash vega, as the days to expiry have halved.